# Set share permissions to Everyone FullControl with CIM CmdLets

Tags: powershell, permissions

We're trying to write a function for a Windows server 2008 machine that needs to remove all the current trustees from the ACL of the share permissions and add the group `Everyone` with `FullControl` access. It would be great if we could use the faster CIM CmdLets for this instead of WMI.

**Code:**

```
$ShareName = 'Folder'

$trustee = New-CimInstance (Get-CimClass Win32_Trustee) -ClientOnly
$trustee.Domain = $null
$trustee.Name = 'EVERYONE'

$ace = New-CimInstance (Get-CimClass Win32_ACE) -ClientOnly
$ace.AccessMask = [Uint32][System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::FullControl
$ace.AceFlags = [Uint32][System.Security.AccessControl.AceFlags]::None
$ace.AceType = [Uint32][System.Security.AccessControl.AceType]::AccessAllowed
$ace.Trustee = $trustee

$sd = New-CimInstance (Get-CimClass Win32_SecurityDescriptor) -ClientOnly
$sd.DACL = $ace
$sd.group = $trustee
$sd.owner = $trustee

$lss = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting -filter "Name='$ShareName'"
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $lss -MethodName SetSecurityDescriptor -Arguments @{Descriptor = $sd}
```

A part of the [code](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=CxlKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA280&lpg=PA280&dq=SetSecurityDescriptor+cimmethod&source=bl&ots=HkXcZxRzE5&sig=wlGFUCTx49JchBlED46K2r5YOw0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEjpL0soLcAhUFXRQKHQ9TBiAQ6AEIPDAD#v=onepage&q&f=false) was found here.

When executing the last line:

```
Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $lss -MethodName SetSecurityDescriptor -Arguments @{Descriptor = $sd}
```

The output `ReturnValue 21` is generated. After some Googling it appears to be about an [Invalid parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393592(v=vs.85).aspx). But we don't see what we're missing here...

Comment: What do you get when you run $lss.GetSecurityDescriptor().Descriptor  ? Is it showing you the descriptor correctly or something that doesn't look right?

Comment: Something that doesn't look right. I.e. still the old values as if nothing was changed.